# Exclude link from Javascript Random Generator

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to exclude specific links from the random_all javascript generator.

I have an archive blog page with a list of links, where I am creating a random button. However, the random link script below takes ANY links from the page. I would like to exclude a few links so that they wouldn't be included as a possibility in the script ( for instance: my home page, or contact page ... just the blog posts displayed on the page)

http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/tester - page can be found here

```
    <script>
    function random_all(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*(document.links.length-1))
    window.location=document.links[myrandom].href
    } 
    //-->
    </script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-Eoin Thomas

Comment: What determines if a link is good or not?

Comment: I want to keep it from redirecting to social links or contact pages and just redirect to content links.

Comment: Ok, fine, but what is the algorithm for that? We can't just guess at what you want.

Comment: I am using it for [http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/archive](http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/archive)  Where I have a list of links. When I generate a random link using `random_all()` it also includes links like navigation, and i would like to create a script that excludes specific links, to then not include the navigation links in the random equation.

Comment: All links are for navigation. Can you be specific as to what about a link would cause it to be on your "exclude" list?

Comment: Question is not clear at all.

Comment: I have Updated the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, since `Math.random()` gets a number between 0 and .9 repeating *(never 1)*, you want change that to a logical expression. Then you run a loop... or better yet, make an `inArray` function. If there aren't too many exclusions then you can use recursion.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, I, inArray, randLinker, old; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
inArray = function(v, a){
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a[i] === v){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
randLinker = function(){
  var exclude = [].slice.call(arguments), lnx = doc.links;
  var randLink = lnx[Math.floor(Math.random()*lnx.length)];
  var randHref = randLink.href;
  if(randLink === this || inArray(randHref, exclude)){
    return randLinker.apply(this, exclude);
  }
  this.href = randHref;
}
I('frm').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
var rand_link = I('rand_link');
rand_link.onclick = function(){
  randLinker.call(this, 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions');
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#frm>a{
  float:left; clear:left;
}
.cb{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Random Link</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='frm' name='frm'>
      <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration'>Loops and iteration</a>
      <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions'>Functions</a>
      <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators'>Expressions and Operators</a>
      <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates'>Numbers and dates</a>
      <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting'>Text formatting</a>
      <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions'>Regular Expressions</a>
      <a id='rand_link' href=''>Random Link</a>
    </form>
    <div class='cb'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `randLinker` takes any amount of arguments. Every one will be excluded. Make sure to call this function in the context of the random link.

Comment: This is awesome. Though in reading it over I think this code actually accomplishes the opposite of what I'm asking. :) I'm looking to have a random link that generates from the whole document, that then excludes certain websites/links. :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Here's what the code does. It looks over all the document.links, including the one that is `randLinker` is called in the context of. If for some reason it's that link that is randomly selected, or any of the links that are passed into `randLinker()`, the function executes again. This means when you click on the `Random Link` it will go to any link that is on the page, that is not in the exclusions. What did you want?

Comment: Thank You. Testing this now and it looks like it's working. Is it possible to format this script to execute when the page loads?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this script isn't working either. :( testing it here [http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/tester](http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/tester)

Comment: Doesn't work? Please explain. When you click `Random Link` it should work. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @PHPglue It works. He does not try even to understand how it works. Just another copy-paste guy..

Comment: :( I understand the script, it's just for some reason still not executing within my example. http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/tester if you click it enough times, it still include the excluded addresses.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is setting up an array of pages / sites that you wish to exclude. Then you can run your code that redirects (or runs `console.log()` in my example) inside of an `if` condition that checks that the array does not include the randomly-generated link's `href` value.

This can be done with the ES6 method **[`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**. Because you don't want the array to include the value, you simply need to check that `includes()` returns false.

This can be seen in the following, where the logic will only trigger for StackOverflow and Twitter:

```js
var exclusions = ['http://www.facebook.com/', 'http://www.google.com/']

function random_all() {
  var myrandom = Math.round(Math.random() * (document.links.length - 1));
  if (!exclusions.includes(document.links[myrandom].href)) {
    //window.location = document.links[myrandom].href;
    console.log(document.links[myrandom].href);
  }
  else {
    console.log('The random link is on the exclusion list!');
  }
}

random_all();
```

```html
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a><br>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a><br>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Trying this now. Would this change the link to run the random_all script?

Comment: `random_all_script()` can be called however you want; on page load, on button click, on hover of one of the links -- it really doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 0):

This will filter out all blacklisted links from `document.links` and then randomize only whitelist:

```js
var blacklist = ["javascript:random_all()", "https://google.com/"];

function random_all(){
    var whitelist = Array.from(document.links).filter(item => !blacklist.includes(item.href));
    if (whitelist.length === 0) {
      alert('No whitelisted links!')
      return;
    }
    // 0<->(whitelist.length-1)
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*(whitelist.length-1))
    console.log(whitelist[myrandom].href);
    //window.location=whitelist[myrandom].href
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>
<a href="https://github.com/">Github</a>

<a href="javascript:random_all()">Random</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Where would I add the blacklist link addresses?

Comment: @Mr.Sharkey updated. I commented window.location change for snippet use..

Comment: So each new black listed address would be a new line correct?  also, could you please demonstrate what the link would be to run this script? would it be `<a href="javascript:random_all(whitelist)">RANDOM</a>` ?

Comment: @Mr.Sharkey I updated it again for you. It should be clear enough. console says where you would go if you uncomment window.location..

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @bigless. For some reason i'm still having issues getting this script to load. I'm testing it on [http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/tester](http://www.eointhomassharkey.com/tester)  and the random link doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Mr.Sharkey Use browser's console to debug errors. You have syntax error in your array declaration.. And you did not uncommented //window.location so now you will only see console.log of page where to go..